# Logistic Unit Fixed Effect Model in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, panel-data

I'm trying to estimate a logistic unit fixed effects model for panel data using R. My dependent variable is binary and measured daily over two years for 13 locations.
The goal of this model is to predict the value of y for a particular day and location based on x.

```
zero <- seq(from=0, to=1, by=1)
ids = dplyr::data_frame(location=seq(from=1, to=13, by=1))
dates = dplyr::data_frame(date = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by="days"))
data = merge(dates, ids)
data$y <- sample(zero, size=9503, replace=TRUE)
data$x <- sample(zero, size=9503, replace=TRUE)
```

While surveying the available packages to do so, I've read a number of ways to (apparently) do this, but I'm not confident I've understood the differences between packages and approaches.

From what I have read so far, `glm()`, `survival::clogit()` and `pglm::pglm()` can be used to do this, but I'm wondering if there are substantial differences between the packages and what those might be. 
Here are the calls I've used:
`fixed <- glm(y ~ x + factor(location), data=data)`
`fixed <- clogit(y ~ x + strata(location), data=data)`

One of the reasons for this insecurity is the error I get when using pglm (also see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146434/why-pglm-fails-for-within-model)) that `pglm` can't use the "within" model:
`fixed <- pglm(y ~ x, data=data, index=c("location", "date"), model="within", family=binomial("logit"))`.

What distinguishes the "within" model of pglm from the approaches in `glm()` and `clogit()` and which of the three would be the correct one to take here when trying to predict y for a given date and unit?

Comment: After reading `?glm` you should be able to answer your first question. Multipart questions are discouraged on SO. Please read [MCVE] and use the [edit] facilities to narrow your question and provide a specific example of a task to be coded.

Comment: After reading ?glm I was not able to answer my first question, which is why I asked here. I have however reformulated my question and made it reproducible.

Comment: Error: 'date_frame' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see that you have defined a proper hypothesis to test within the context of what you are calling "panel data", but as far as getting `glm` to give estimates for logistic coefficients within strata it can be accomplished by adding family="binomial" and stratifying by your "unit" variable:

```
> fixed <- glm(y ~ x + strata(unit), data=data, family="binomial")
> fixed

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x + strata(unit), family = "binomial", data = data)

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)                    x   strata(unit)unit=2   strata(unit)unit=3  
            0.10287             -0.05910             -0.08302             -0.03020  
 strata(unit)unit=4   strata(unit)unit=5   strata(unit)unit=6   strata(unit)unit=7  
           -0.06876             -0.05042             -0.10200             -0.09871  
 strata(unit)unit=8   strata(unit)unit=9  strata(unit)unit=10  strata(unit)unit=11  
           -0.09702              0.02742             -0.13246             -0.04816  
strata(unit)unit=12  strata(unit)unit=13  
           -0.11449             -0.16986  

Degrees of Freedom: 9502 Total (i.e. Null);  9489 Residual
Null Deviance:      13170 
Residual Deviance: 13170    AIC: 13190
```

That will not take into account any date-ordering, which is what I would have expected to be the interest. But as I said above, there doesn't yet appear to be a hypothesis that is premised on any sequential ordering.

This would create a fixed effects model that included a spline relationship of `date` to probability of y-event. I chose to center the date rather than leaving it as a very large integer:

```
library(splines)
fixed <- glm(y ~ x + ns(scale(date),3) + factor(unit), data=data, family="binomial")
fixed
#----------------------
Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x + ns(scale(date), 3) + factor(unit), family = "binomial", 
    data = data)

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)                    x  ns(scale(date), 3)1  ns(scale(date), 3)2  
            0.13389             -0.05904              0.04431             -0.10727  
ns(scale(date), 3)3        factor(unit)2        factor(unit)3        factor(unit)4  
           -0.03224             -0.08302             -0.03020             -0.06877  
      factor(unit)5        factor(unit)6        factor(unit)7        factor(unit)8  
           -0.05042             -0.10201             -0.09872             -0.09702  
      factor(unit)9       factor(unit)10       factor(unit)11       factor(unit)12  
            0.02742             -0.13246             -0.04816             -0.11450  
     factor(unit)13  
           -0.16987  

Degrees of Freedom: 9502 Total (i.e. Null);  9486 Residual
Null Deviance:      13170 
Residual Deviance: 13160    AIC: 13200
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer/comment, that clarified perfectly what I'm struggling with. I've updated my question with the goal that I want to accomplish: I want to predict y for a given day based on x. How would I go about sequential ordering in this context?

Comment: Using your fixed effects code (adapted for my dataset) results in my R freezing (or at least, keeps running for very long time). There are no warnings or anything, so it's difficult to say what is wrong. Any ideas? I will try the survival package next, having also failed to get a result using pglm (see CV: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146434/why-pglm-fails-for-within-model).

Comment: @Deleet With no data this comment doesn't have much meaning or possibility of substantive response. It's just saying some unspecified data object of unspecified nature caused some undesired behavior.

Comment: It turns out that if one leaves R running for 30 mins, it does fit in the end. I ended up using the clogit function from survival, which produced similar output but had near instant fitting time. (My data are proprietary so I can't share them.)

Comment: why do you include an intercept here? In a linear fixed effects model, the individual constants should be collinear with the intercept, no? Is this not the case in this logit with strata?