# Extracting linear predictors from general linear model for panel data ( pglm )

Tags: r, extract, panel, glm, coefficients

I would like to extract linear predictors out of a pglm model.

With a basic glm model, it can be done simply using the command $linear.predictors

```
#For example

library(plm)
library(pglm)
data(UnionWage)  # from pglm-package
punions <- pdata.frame(UnionWage, c("id", "year"))
punions <- subset(punions, wage > 0)

glm.model <- glm(wage ~ exper + rural + married, data=punions, family = "poisson")
glm.model$linear.predictors
```

How can I extract or compute linear predictors from a pglm model like

```
pglm.model <- pglm(wage ~ exper + rural + married, data=punions, model="random", family="poisson")
```

I hope anybody can help!

Comment: There is no possibility to make the prediction for the `pglm` function directly. It's better to use `glm` as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45219282/11570343).